# How to encode space character in XML url using curl

Tags: xml, url, curl, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to install jenkins plugins using the jenkins api. I am able to install a plugin successfully when the plugin name is just a single word (no space character). It however fails when the plugin name has more than one single word (space characters). For example

```
curl -u admin:changepassword -X POST -d '<jenkins><install plugin="start windocks containers@1.4" /></jenkins>' --header 'Content-Type: text/xml' http://localhost:8080/pluginManager/installNecessaryPlugins
```

wont work because of the space characters. I have tried escaping it with %20 and others like   but still cant get it to work.

Comment: I don't think curl is going to be the problem here - presumably, it's already transmitting the space between `install` and `plugin` just fine. Your problem is presumably how Jenkins interprets the value of that `plugin` attribute, and what the correct name for `start windocks containers` should be; e.g. maybe it needs to be written as `start-windocks-containers` or `StartWindocksContainers`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your xml post data in a file and posting using `--data-binary "@path/to/file"` instead of -d 'inline post data'? If this doesn't work, maybe encoding it with `&#032;`